# Add NavigationController to current view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm using a UIScrollView to display some images, and i need to present or push another view when the user selects one part of the image.This ScrollView is created only programmatically.
How i can programmatically add a navigationController to it and present another view?

I tried this way but just give me the following error :

> Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'

```
 StatesViewController * controller = [[StatesViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"StatesViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController * Navcontroller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

    [self presentModalViewController: Navcontroller animated: YES];
```

Comment: Why not embed the UIScrollView in a UINavigationController?

Comment: The ScrollView is created programmatically, i don't know exactly how to implement a navigationController to it

Comment: But what is the `UIScrollView` being created in? Surely it's being added as a subview of a `UIView` already contained in a `UIViewController`, or is being assigned as *the* `view` of a `UIViewController`? Just change that `UIViewController` so that it's wrapped in a `UINavigationController`, and you should then be able to push new view controllers on the stack. (You can even hide the navigation item of the `UINavigationController` on the first screen if you don't want users to see it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might help you.

```
 NextViewController *nextViewController=[[NextViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navBar=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:nextViewController];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navBar animated:YES];
```