# pushViewController not working in xib in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using a xibs and swift, is there a way i can use `pushViewController` to go to another view and come back programatically ?

Error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Things i've tried:

1. Setting it to root view doesn't allow to go back

2.

> ```
> let rvc: LoginViewController = LoginViewController()
> self.navigationController!.pushViewController(rvc, animated: true)
> ```

And if i change from `navigationController!` to `navigationController?` nothing happens

Comment: are you sure you have navigation controller there , from where you trying to push., if no then try to present or  take navigation controller to inital i controller and make your vc to root view controller , then push

Comment: No, i don't have because i'm using xibs, i tried Embed In > Navigation Controller but its disabled

Comment: when you create object from xib of your view controller like MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil]; add with Navigation controller root vc like     [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourController]

Comment: see answer i posted

Comment: are you using xibs and storyboard both in project? or just using xibs.

Comment: I'm using only xib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `navigationController` property (`self.navigationController`) of a view controller will return a valid navigation controller object only if the view controller is in a navigation controller's navigation stack.

You could try to embed a navigationController like in this picture:

[image]

Or create it programmatically:

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self)
```

After that you can push a viewController.

**Update after comments**:
 About your error:

```
It ran into error adding a root view controller <collegeSystem.FirstViewController: 0x7c280330> as a child of view controller:<UINavigationController: 0x7c91bc00>
```

it seems you try to do this:

```
self.window.addSubview(navigationController.view)
```

instead of :

```
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController
```

Comment: I tried that but the button is disabled, is it because of AutoLayout is On ?

Comment: Have you try to click on the yellow box File Owner ? Than go to Editor..

Comment: No , autolayout does not matter in this case.

Comment: I see, I don't know your code but by reading your error I've try to update my answer

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
let vc = LoginViewController(nibName: "LoginViewController", bundle: nil)
 self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

or try this

```
if let vc = LoginViewController(nibName: "LoginViewController", bundle: nil)
{
 self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

if your VC not added in `navigation controller` use like

```
 if let vc = LoginViewController(nibName: "LoginViewController", bundle: nil)
{
  self.presentViewController(vc, animated:true, completion:nil)
}
```

Comment: It didn't gave error because of `?` but it didn't go to another controller , u have any idea why ?Do i need to initialize navigationController ?

Comment: `presentViewController` worked but the effect is wrong it shouldn't come from down. That is why i was using `pushViewController` :(

Answer (score 1):

The navigation controller, which you are trying to access is nil. Try printing it to verify.

```
print(self.navigationController)
```

Comment: Yes it is `nil` , do u know how to initialize the navigationController that its not `nil` , thanks btw

Comment: If the view is already embedded in navigation controller, your code should work just fine. I think that is not the case now. So you can create a navigation controller programmatically and set your view controller as rootViewController and present that navigation controller modally.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412526/add-navigationcontroller-to-current-view

Answer (score 1):

Take view controller object from xib

```
YourViewcontroller *viewController  = // load from xib
```

Then

```
 UINavigationController *mainVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourController]
```

and set root view controller

```
[self.window setRootViewController:mainVC]
```

now you able to push

Comment: Hi mike, this question is flagged as Swift , not objective C.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the navigation controller for the first view:

   - Select the first ViewController where you want to segue from
   - At the top interface of Xcode -> `Editor` -> `Embeded In` -> `Navigation Controller`
2. Make a segue:

> ```
> > let vc = NewViewController(nibName: "NewViewController", bundle: nil)
> > self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try This, I have face error message while push to view controller,

Error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Before push to view controller we have to do initialisation of **window** as mention in below code

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

   // Do initialisation of window to avoid error message 

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds);
    let vc = HomeViewController(nibName: "HomeViewController", bundle: nil)
    nav.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
    // Set the window’s root view controller
    self.window!.rootViewController = nav
    // Present the window
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible() 
    return true
    }
```